# How do we pronounce "/etc" folder?

Tags: linux, unix

How do we pronounce "/etc" folder?

Is it only 3 letter e,t and c?

Comment: However you want.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about English language and usage, not particularly related to computer software, and primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @slhck Can you migrate the question to http://english.stackexchange.com/? It's a valuable question.

Comment: @nixda No, sorry. It's still entirely based on personal preference ("I pronounce it like this: …", "I've always heard people say …", etc.)

Comment: @shlck: This is not an English language question, because it seems that the name of the /etc directory (present in every UNIX and Linux system, independently from localization) is frequently pronounced differently than the corresponding English word "etc.".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is no official pronunciation.  It is an abbreviation  for "[et cetera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_cetera)" and used as for system-wide configuration files and system databases.

Everyone I know pronounces it "et see"

Comment: so should be "e" "t" "see", right?

Comment: @KitHo, no 'et' is one sound. 'et-see' is two syllables.

Comment: Like that Arts 'n Crafts website Etsy... Which is where it came from.

Comment: I guess a better way word to sum it up would be "etsee"

Comment: Or if you are Finnish, "ee-tee-see" :)

Comment: I have always though of "etsee" at the old-school Unix hacker pronunciation, while less experienced types say "e-t-c" and hardly anyone says "et cetera". I'm in the "etsee" camp myself.

Comment: "et cetera" in the UK

Comment: I "slash et cetera", also in UK

Comment: I've always called it "et cetera", because that's obviously what it stands for and I'd never heard anyone else pronounce it. "Et-see" is interesting..

Comment: I've never thought of "etsee" being old school, I've been involved with Linux and BSD for about 25 years and I always heard "et cetera" or "e-t-c" and I don't ever recall anyone saying "etsee" until about 6 years ago when some young Ubuntu-user was heavily confused by a SCO installation from the 80s. When he said "etsee" I didn't know what he meant at first. I have heard it since then, but only from young people. I myself say "et cetera" and always have.

Comment: et-see can be heard in this video: https://youtu.be/LJLDd2gScas?t=4m14s

Answer (score 17):

Everyone I know who is non native English speaking say "slash ee tee cee", otherwise, looks like there is no consensus ...

Comment: I know several people from England and Holland who pronounce it "etsy" however I dont remember if they said that from the time the came to America.  I know we used to make fun of them for saying "rooter" for router.  They eventually switched to the American pronunciation.

Comment: @Keltari: pronouncing router as "rooter" is perfectly acceptable. The reason is that route is pronounced "root" in british english; there is no pronunciative distinction between root and route in british english. As it stands: rowter is A.E. while rooter is B.E. but both are acceptable in their own right.

Answer (score 9):

Everywhere I have been has said "et cetera" or "E T C" never heard of "et see".

NB - also it can be said 'X cetera'.

Comment: Everyone I know says "et cetera".

Comment: @Nick Never heard "et cetera" in that context. Do you really mean you hear sentences like "The configuration file is in et cetera" ? That sounds very odd to me.

Comment: @jlliagre As in "The file is in "slash et cetera" ie /etc since you write et cetera as etc.

Comment: @jlliagr yes just as in your sentence. Edit the smb.conf in your "et cetera" config directory, for example.

Comment: @Nick and David, Interesting. I'm used to "slash user vs you ess er" and "slash temp vs tee em pee" but never heard (or more probably just didn't notice) "slash et cetera".

Comment: @jlliagre I'm rather confused by the apparent amount of people who say that everyone else is saying "etsee" when I've only heard it a few times from a few young people, mostly Ubuntu users. For me pronouncing it "etsee" is sort of like pronouncing "usr" as "yoosser" or something.

Comment: @simontemplar I am not one of the people who say everyone else is saying "etsee", on the opposite I observe there is no consensus between native English speaker while non native tend to pronounce each letter separately like "slash ee tee cee".

Comment: @jlliagre I apologise I didn't mean to imply that you had said that, what I meant was for it to be a follow up to what you were saying, and even in this question there are at least a couple of people who are indeed saying that and after doing some web searching I saw some others as well, and I just find it odd because it's so new to me despite being around the environment for so long

Comment: @simontemplar No problem. I found both "et cetera" (which I never noticed in that context) and "etsee" (which I heard from US people) odd and always use "ee tee cee" but I'm far to be authoritative, being a non native English speaker.

Answer (score 5):

Purely anecdotal, but

- all the North Americans I know say 'et-see' (with emphasis on the first syllable)
- all the British people I know say 'ee - tee - see'
- all the non-native English speakers I know use either one of the above, or try to make it into a word.  Commonly heard is 'eat - see'.

Sometimes people say 'slash' beforehand depending on context and audience.

Comment: I've only ever heard a couple of North Americans say "etsee" most say "e-t-c" or sometimes more technical people will say "et cetera" but I think maybe the Linux/BSD users I'm around are older and it may be generational, as "etsee" I've only ever heard from 20-something Ubuntu users here in North America, and only in the last 6 - 8 years or so. I'm pretty out of touch with reality in general though ;)

Comment: I'm 31, from the U.S., and would never have thought to say 'etsee'. I've always said 'ee tee see'. Then again, most of my 'conversations' about linux have been confined to writing.

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple - slash 'e' 't' 'c'